# More efficient methods to show that something is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the $5\times 5$ matrix $A$, $$A = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & -1 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\ -4 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -3 & -2 \\ -4 & -2 & -1 & 5 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -2 & -3 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$ Show that $A$ has characteristic polynomial  $(t+1)^2(t-2)^3$.

I already know how to determine the characteristic polynomial of $A$ from scratch, but I am interested in whether there is a more efficient method to check whether a given polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix. The best idea I could come up with is to check that the dimension of $\lambda=-1$ is $2$ and the dimension of $\lambda=2$ is $3$, but this method involves a lot of row reductions. Is there are a more efficient method?

Comment: When you say "dimension", do you mean the dimension of the eigenspaces? If yes, then you probably get a wrong conclusion, since the dimension of the eigenspace, i.e. the geometric multiplicities is always **less than or equal to** the index of $t-c$ in the characteristic polynomial, i.e. the algebraic multiplicity, and the $<$ could happen.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the dimension of the eigenspaces. That is a good point, so then the method I came up with wouldn't work.